# Query SQL Database so result will be as tree view

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, select, dropdown, razor-pages

I have razor page menu that has three level of drop-down
values are saved in three tables in SQL Database and are linked with parent id

Table Directory
directoryId, DirectoryName

Table Department
departmentId, DepartmentName, DirectoryId

Table Sector
sectorId, SectorName, DepartmentId

so the logic is that each directory has its own departments that have own sectors
i need help how to query Tables so result would be in a way of tree view

Comment: Hover over the tag "sql", read the flyout: "Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. **Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data**, and **a tag for the DBMS implementation** (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), **use that DBMS's tag** instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL."

Comment: It's up to you how your web app renders the tree. What treeview library / approach are you using in your web page?

Comment: Have a try with this one. If it works for you you can use `FOR JSON` in your SQL query to pre format your data as JSON https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47589208/how-to-create-tree-view-table-from-array-of-objects-javascript

Comment: When you say tree view do you mean one big static tree displayed as a report, or something that is active, allows opening/closing nodes etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using MSSQL, and in the absence of any sample data, I think the TSQL query could be:

```
WITH tree_view AS (
    SELECT directoryId, DirectoryName, CAST(DirectoryName AS VARCHAR(1024)) AS tree
    FROM Directory
    UNION ALL
    SELECT d.departmentId, d.DepartmentName, tree_view.tree + ' > ' + d.DepartmentName
    FROM Department d
    JOIN tree_view ON tree_view.directoryId = d.DirectoryId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT s.sectorId, s.SectorName, tree_view.tree + ' > ' + s.SectorName
    FROM Sector s
    JOIN tree_view ON tree_view.departmentId = s.DepartmentId
)
SELECT * FROM tree_view;
```

If you are not using MSSQL you can probably use double pipes `||` instead of plus symbols to perform the concatenations, or use a CONCAT() function.